# context.sendActivity(CardFactory.oauthCard(...)) seems much simpler, but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, botframework

I was hoping to write the authentication step myself instead of clone the samples repository so I can get a better understanding. Trying to keep it simple, I changed the `onTurn` function to:

```
public onTurn = async (context: TurnContext) => {
    if (context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
        await context.sendActivity(CardFactory.oauthCard( ... );
    }
};
```

But when I test it in the bot emulator, no oauth card shows up, nor any other response. But when I test the *bot-authentication-msgraph* sample in GitHub, it works fine. Can't I just use the one-line of code to authenticate users: `context.sendActivity(CardFactory.oauthCard( ... )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CardFactory.oauthCard` will build a card as an *attachment*, but you still have to *add it to an activity* to send it out. This should do what you're looking for:

```js
await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.oauthCard(...)));
```